# how to save Web C# Bitmap object to Server disk

Tags: c#

how to save Web C# Bitmap object to Server disk

Comment: You should accept answers to your questions by clicking the hollow check mark next to your favorite answer for each question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call [`Bitmap.Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.save.aspx) on the server.

For a more specific answer, ask a more detailed question.

Comment: Couldn't have put it better myself! ;)